# Why does the code print as much as it gets characters

Tags: c

This is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, num3 = 0, num4 = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("choose 4 numbers, you dont need space\n");
        scanf("%1d%1d%1d%1d", &num1, &num2, &num3, &num4);
        if(!num1 || !num2 || !num3 || !num4)
        {
            getchar();
        }
    }
    while (num1 != num2 || num1 != num3 || num1 != num4 ||
           num2 != num3 || num2 != num4 || num3 != num4); 

}
```

I don't know what to do with that.

If the input is, for example. `*/*-` then
the output is:

```
choose 4 numbers, you dont need space 
choose 4 numbers, you dont need space 
choose 4 numbers, you dont need space 
choose 4 numbers, you dont need space
```

Comment: You need to check what [`scanf` *returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value)!

Comment: And for future questions, please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve] (one that actually exhibits the problem you have).

Comment: The scanf() functions leave any character that can’t be part of the conversion unread, so the next input will try to process it. If the input is only `*/*-`, then the program exits because the 4 numbers are all equal (all zero). If you type one or more non-zero digits and then some non-numeric characters, then you get one prompt for each character that isn't white space (white space is skipped by the `%d` format). If you indicate EOF in the error state, you get an indefinite loop. If you reach a point where the numbers are all the same, the loop ends. The `getchar()` is what makes it happen.

Comment: Quirky information: the `num1 != num2` … conditions using `num1` are sufficient; those tests starting `num2 !=` or `num3 !=` are never change the loop condition. Suppose you have 1, 3, 3, 4; then the `num1 != num2` test is true, and the other conditions are not evaluated. It doesn't matter how you change the numbers; if the numbers are not all the same, one of the first 3 tests evaluates to true and the others are not evaluated. If you have 3, 3, 3, 3 in the numbers, then all the tests evaluate to false, but the `num2 !=` and `num3 !=` tests are never going to fail if the `num1 !=` ones don't.

Comment: regarding: `while (num1 != num2 || num1 != num3 || num1 != num4 ||
           num2 != num3 || num2 != num4 || num3 != num4);`  this is checking that all 4 numbers are unique.  Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code behaves as you describe because the `scanf` function does not touch the reading buffer when the convertion cannot take place. Calling the function in loop will try to read the next characters as `%d`.

Entering a non-numeric sequence will never stop your code as expected.
For this reason, you should check the return value of `scanf` in order to detect bad inputs.